# runtime error 1004 excel-vba

Tags: vba, excel

The error line is:

```
If Sheets(1).Cells(6, i).Value = "AC POWER (LVL1)" Then
```

Code:

```
Function getParam(Parameter As String)
    'For Testing Purposes

    Dim paramList, columnVals
    Dim lastRow, lastCol, currentRow, currentCol, lvl1, foundCol As Long
    Dim role8Loc, acpowerLoc, paramLoc, role8for2 As Long

    lastRow = Sheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
    lastCol = Sheets(1).Range("A6").CurrentRegion.columns.Count
    currentRow = 4 'Sheets(2).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    currentCol = 60

    paramList = Array("LESS100", "LNA200 COOL", _
                      "LNA200 POWER", "MEGA100", _
                      "MEGA1000", "MEGA200", _
                      "MEGA500")

    'Get Role(8) Location
    For i = 1 To lastCol
        If Sheets(1).Cells(6, i).Value = "Role (8)" Then
            role8Loc = i
        End If
    Next i

    'Get AC POWER (LVL1) Location
    For i = role8Loc To lastCol
        If Sheets(1).Cells(6, i).Value = "AC POWER (LVL1)" Then
            acpowerLoc = i
        End If
```

I didn't include full code on the file cause I think it's not necessary.

Comment: What is the value of `role8Loc` when the error occurs ?

Comment: @Robin Mackenzie its empty.

Comment: OK that's the problem then. `role8Loc` should be a value between 1 and tha max number of columns depending on your version of Excel. It's likely that there was no cell with a value of `Role (8)` in your previous loop. You need an `If` statement to validate `role8Loc` before you run the second loop. HTH

Comment: @RobinMackenzie so what block of codes should I add and where exactly?

Comment: Please do not replace one question with a different question - it completely invalidates all the answers that have been provided, and makes the question absolutely useless for anyone else who comes across it when searching for the solution for a similar problem.  I have rolled it back to the original version and recommend you paste the latest problem as a new question.

Comment: @YowE3K ohh, sorry man. Im just gonna post a new one then.

Answer (score 0):

First-up you should do:

```
Dim role8Loc As Long
```

Becuase at the moment it is a `Variant` - you need to do `Dim x As y` for every variabled and not do `Dim x, y, z As Long` because otherwise `x` and `y` will be `Variant`.

Then, in this loop there is a chance that no cell has the value of `Role (8)` and therefore `role8Loc` will be 0 (or empty if you left as a `Variant`).

```
'Get Role(8) Location
For i = 1 To lastCol
    If Sheets(1).Cells(6, i).Value = "Role (8)" Then
        role8Loc = i
    End If
Next i
```

If `role8Loc` is 0 then you can't use it as a value for the `Cells` collection because there is no 0 column. So before the next loop, do an `If` check:

```
If IsEmpty(role8Loc) Or role8Loc < 1 Then
  MsgBox "Error!"
  Exit Sub
End If
```

Then when you do this loop:

```
'Get AC POWER (LVL1) Location
For i = role8Loc To lastCol
    If Sheets(1).Cells(6, i).Value = "AC POWER (LVL1)" Then
        acpowerLoc = i
    End If
Next i
```

Then `i` should be at least 1 - and you should not get an error on this line:

```
If Sheets(1).Cells(6, i).Value = "AC POWER (LVL1)" Then
```

So your final code will be:

```
Function getParam(Parameter As String)
    'For Testing Purposes

    Dim paramList, columnVals
    Dim lastRow, lastCol, currentRow, currentCol, lvl1, foundCol As Long
    ' explicitly set these variables to Long
    Dim role8Loc As Long, acpowerLoc As Long, paramLoc As Long, role8for2 As Long

    lastRow = Sheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
    lastCol = Sheets(1).Range("A6").CurrentRegion.columns.Count
    currentRow = 4 'Sheets(2).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    currentCol = 60

    paramList = Array("LESS100", "LNA200 COOL", _
                      "LNA200 POWER", "MEGA100", _
                      "MEGA1000", "MEGA200", _
                      "MEGA500")

    'Get Role(8) Location
    role8Loc = 0 '<~~ initialise variable to 0
    For i = 1 To lastCol
        If Sheets(1).Cells(6, i).Value = "Role (8)" Then
            role8Loc = i
        End If
    Next i

    ' validating role8Loc
    If role8Loc < 1 Then '<~~ test if variable changed
      MsgBox "Error!"
      Exit Function '<~~ exit if variable has not changed
    End If

    'Get AC POWER (LVL1) Location
    For i = role8Loc To lastCol 
        ' no error if i starts from a value >=1
        If Sheets(1).Cells(6, i).Value = "AC POWER (LVL1)" Then
            acpowerLoc = i
        End If
    Next i
```

Comment: See the edit with your full code block - made a few changes

Comment: now it says compile error: Exit sub is not allowed in function or property :/

Comment: Changed to `Exit Function`

Comment: there is no error anymore, but the MsgBox still appears. what now? if it pops out it means that the value of role8Loc is still 0, right?

Comment: I think that you need to go back over your code carefully - maybe step through with F8 and check what is happening step by step. I get the impression you aren't 100% across what your code is doing. Maybe once you do that you should a new question. Good luck.

Comment: @nubcoder17 - As you step through the code using F8, check what value `lastCol` is being set to, and then make sure that one of the cells in row 6 is "Role (8)" **and it is not after the column number represented by `lastCol`**.  Your heading may be in a column beyond the extent of cell A6's `CurrentRegion`.

Comment: hi again @YowE3K! the value of lastCol is = 1054. let me check again something. @.@

Comment: @nubcoder17 - that's column ANN so, providing there is a cell somewhere within the range `A6:ANN6` that contains the value `"Role (8)"` (that **exact** value, not `"ROLE (8)"`, not `"Role  (8)"` with two spaces, not `"Role (8) "` with a trailing space, not `"Role 8"`, not `"My Role (8) value"`, etc), `role8Loc` should be getting set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid loops by using `Find()` function to look a given range (some *headers* range I guess) for a cell with a given value and get back found cell `Range` object (if found) or `Nothing` (if not found)

Finally check for possible typos: your code has a `If Sheets(1).Cells(6, i).Value = "Role (8)" Then` line but its introducing comment says `'Get Role(8) Location` -> the two strings differ for a space

For all what above the following code could help you in getting started again (I just commented out your code lines not strictly necessary for what I'm showing you)

```
Function getParam(Parameter As String) '<--| where is 'Parameter' used?

    Dim paramList ', columnVals
    'Dim lastRow As Long, currentRow As Long, currentCol As Long, lvl1 As Long, foundCol As Long
    Dim role8Loc As Long, acpowerLoc  As Long ', paramLoc As Long, role8for2 As Long
    Dim headers As Range, found As Range

    With Sheets(1) '<--| reference relevant sheet
'        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Set headers = .Range("A6", .Cells(6, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)) '<--| set the range with headers to search through
    End With

'    With Sheets(2) '<--| reference relevant sheet
'        currentRow = 4 '.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
'        currentCol = 60 '.Range("A6", .Cells(6, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
'    End With

'    paramList = Array("LESS100", "LNA200 COOL", _
'                      "LNA200 POWER", "MEGA100", _
'                      "MEGA1000", "MEGA200", _
'                      "MEGA500") '<--| where is this used? 


    Set found = headers.Find(what:="Role (8)", after:=headers(headers.Columns.Count), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) '<--| try and get "Role (8)" Location (check it should not be "Role(8)"!)

    If found Is Nothing Then '<--| if not found
        MsgBox "No matches for 'Role (8)' keyword in " & headers.Address(False, False)
    Else '<--| if found
        role8Loc = found.Column
        Set found = headers.Resize(, headers.Columns.Count - role8Loc).Offset(, role8Loc).Find(what:="AC POWER (LVL1)", after:=headers(headers.Columns.Count), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) '<--| try and get "AC POWER (LVL1)" Location
        If found Is Nothing Then '<--| if not found
            MsgBox "No matches for 'AC POWER (LVL1)' keyword in " & headers.Address(False, False)
        Else '<--| if found
            acpowerLoc = found.Column
        End If
    End If

    getParam = role8Loc & " - " & acpowerLoc '<--| just to have a return value to show in caller function


End Function
```

Comment: hey there! it is used on different block of codes.                                                                                              lastRow = Sheets("Parameter").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

Comment: well that shouldn't work since `"Parameter"` is a string `literal` (i.e. always having the same value: `"Parameter"`) while `Parameter` is a string variable (i.e. having the value it's been set to). Maybe you want to use it as `lastRow = Sheets(Parameter).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row`. But that is another story,... what about proposed code for your currrent issue?